# How to create a random list using integers of different lengths - Python

Tags: python, list, random

I'm trying to write a line of code that will allow me to create a random list of 5 values, whose lengths I can vary in size. For example, I want the numbers in the list to have a length of 2 or 3 integers, like this: [11, 34, 67, 88, 93] or [100, 450, 622, 875, 998].

So far I have this:

```
import random
mylist = []
for i in range(5):
 p=p+[random.randrange(?????)
 print(p)
```

Can anyone help me as I've been trying to do this all day and it's driving me crazy! Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean 2 or 3 digits? i.e. 10-99 vs 100-999? And is that criteria random for each list, or specified elsewhere?

Comment: Can they have both 2 and 3 digits like `[10, 50, 213, 567]`?

Answer (score 2):

```
n_digits = 3
min_num = 10**(n_digits-1)
max_number = 10**n_digits -1 #thanks @TomKarzes

size_of_list = 5

my_list = [random.randint(min_num,max_num) for i in range(size_of_list)]
```

Comment: I'm sorry Joran, but could I please direct your attention to our chat room?

Answer (score 1):

```
import random
mylist = []
for i in range(5):
    m = random.choice([0,1])
    mylist.append(random.randrange(10*m, (100*m)+1))
    print(mylist)
```

Comment: it took me a while but now I see how you interpreted the OP question ... cool answer assuming you interpreted it right

Answer (score 1):

Use `sample` to take arbitrary value( here 5) from a list

```
>>>import random
>>>random.sample(range(10000),5)# or below
>>>random.sample(range(10,999),5)#2-3 integer numbers range
>>>random.sample(range(10,99),5)#2 integer numbers range
>>>random.sample(range(100,999),5)#3 integer numbers range
```

Comment: `random.sample(range(10, 1000), 5)`

Comment: @user3100115  what do you mean?

Comment: The question is *...create a random list of 5 values*  then *...I want the numbers in the list to have a length of 2 or 3 integers*

Answer (score 0):

```
import random

choices = [(10, 99), (100,999)]

bounds = random.choice(choices)
mylist = [random.randint(*bounds) for i in range(5)]

print mylist
```